# A particular :hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, scale

I'm currently working on a project section there are 3 columns, i already set the scale to change when hovering over one of it, but my client requested that the middle column need to be already scaled when the page is opened for the first time, and after hovering on the one on the left or on the right, the middle column get back to the original scale, the same as the other.

Is possible?

the correct way should be:

0= Original scale

1= Bigger scale

First view of the page->[ 0| 1 |0 ]  --hovering in another column-->[ 1| 0 |0 ] --not hovering in a column->[ 0| 0 |0 ]

I don't know if i was clear enough, sorry for my english but is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Could you please post your code so a specific answer can be provided to solve your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Assign a class to the middle box, to enlarge it initially, and then remove that class as soon as you mouseover another box.

**Edit** - changed event binding from `on` to `one`, per [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)'s suggestion.

```js
$('body').one('mouseover', '.box', function (event) {
  $('.box').removeClass('focussed');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box.focussed,
.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box focussed"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: `.one(` would be enough.

Comment: @Kaiido what do you mean?

Comment: [jQuery *.one()*](http://api.jquery.com/one/)  attaches an event for a single execution (same as `addEventListener(evt, fn, {once: true})`). In that case that would be better than having the event listener still attached for the whole document's life, firing again and again at each mouseover, for no real visible effect.

Comment: Oh nice. I’ve not used jQuery for quite a while, so didn’t know about that function.